# Small sample OLS regression: how to conduct inference?

Tags: regression, inference, least-squares, small-sample

Consider a linear data generating process (DGP)
$$
y=X\beta+\varepsilon, \quad \varepsilon\sim i.i.D(0,\sigma^2)
$$
with some unknown distribution $D$ with zero mean and finite variance $\sigma^2$ (and no perfect multicollinearity in $X$). Suppose we have a small random sample from this DGP. Suppose further we know the DGP up to the distribution of errors and the parameter values. We estimate the latter using OLS.

**Question:** How can we conduct inference about the parameters (e.g. construct a confidence interval or test a hypothesis)?

Some thoughts:
There is no assumption of normality, so we do not have exact normal distribution of $\hat\beta$.
The sample is small, so invoking asymptotic normality does not work.
The sample is small, so bootstrap may not work well, as it relies on asymptotics.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/120174/small-sample-ols-inference?tab=general