# How do I estimate a Bayesian linear regression without assuming normal likelihood?

Tags: regression, bayesian, frequentist

Frequentist linear regression makes no assumptions about the joint distribution beyond finite second moments.

How can I perform similar agnostic Bayesian linear regression, without imposing additional distributional assumptions beyond what is necessary? All examples I have seen assume normal likelihood.

Comment: Sorry—which joint distribution are you referring to? Setting up some notation might help me help you.

Comment: Just a reminder that this seemingly "agnostic" (distribution-free) linear regression is just kicking the can of assumptions down the road. If you don't want to assume normality of the conditional density $f(y|x)$, you have to make the analogous assumption later about the [sampling distribution of the OLS estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/511241) or else you cannot make frequentist inference. There's no free lunch in either paradigm; decisions and assumptions have to made no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to take the opportunity to put my foot in my mouth. What I'm about to say might be wrong, but the easiest way to learn the right answer is to be wrong on the internet.

The Gauss-Markov theorem states that the errors in OLS need not be normal -- hell, they need not even be iid -- in order for OLS to have minimum variance among the class of linear unbiased estimators.  *That does not mean we do not make the Gaussian assumption*, it only means that the Gaussian assumption is not critical for our estimates of the conditional mean.

We make the Gaussian assumption implicitly by minimizing the squared errors.  Indeed, maximizing the Gaussian log likelihood is the same as minimizing the sum of squares, so in my mind whether or not you intend to make the Gaussian assumption is irrelevant; you end up making it anyway and enjoy the results of Gauss-Markov nonetheless.

Now, as for your question, I believe that you require a likelihood for Bayesian analyses. The bayesian perspective puts heavy emphasis on the data generating processes, and that means the likelihood plays a fairly large role (never mind that most sampling techniques require it as well). That being said, you are free to change that likelihood to relax the assumption of normality.  One way to do this would be to assume a student t likelihood and estimate the degrees of freedom.  You can very easily change the likelihood in libraries like brms, pymc3, and Stan.  Here is a small example I wrote in Stan which uses the student t likelihood.

```r
library(cmdstanr)
library(tidybayes)

n = 1000
x = rnorm(n)
y = 2*x + 1 + rt(n, 20)
model_data = list(n=n, x=x, y=y)

model_code = '
data{
  int n;
  vector[n] y;
  vector[n] x;
}
parameters{
  real b1;
  real b0;
  real<lower=0> dof;
  real<lower=0>sigma;
}
model{
  b1 ~ normal(0, 1);
  b0 ~ normal(0,1);
  dof ~ cauchy(0,1);
  sigma ~ gamma(2,2);
  y ~ student_t(dof, b0 + b1*x, sigma);
}
generated quantities{
  real y_ppc[n] = student_t_rng(dof, b0 + b1*x, sigma);
}

'

model_file = write_stan_file(model_code)
model = cmdstan_model(model_file)

fit = model$sample(model_data, adapt_delta = 0.99, parallel_chains=4)
```

In summation, Gauss Markov requires that the errors be homoskedastic and have mean 0.  That means that any distribution which satisfies those should work (in principle).  The difficulty is then picking one and determining if that is a sufficiently good likelihood for your problem.

Comment: I think you are mostly right here (+1) so no foot in mouth as far as I can see.  My only disagreement is that I would say you *can* proceed with OLS without implicitly assuming normality of the error terms --- you just have to accept that certain desirable properties do not follow without that assumption (e.g., you cannot say that the OLS is the MLE).